# Параметры в переменные Powershell скрипта

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, администрирование, powershell, active-directory

Привет всем!Вопрос: есть powershell скрипт, в котором есть переменная, условно $User_name?

Возможно ли сделать так, что бы запускать этот скрипт через scheduler с параметром, который давал бы значение этой переменной?

Т.е. я в задаче ставлю: выполнить "myscript.ps1" параметры: "$User_name="Ololosha Valueva"", и скрипт выполняется для этого пользователя.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Параметры скриптам передаются также как и функциям. Нужно объявить в начале скрипта блок `Param()`, в котором описывается требуемый параметр.

- Подробная документация по параметрам: [about_Functions_Advanced_Parameters](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847743.aspx).
- Вводная статья на русском: [Windows PowerShell: Определение параметров](https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/magazine/jj554301.aspx)

Пример кода:

```powershell
Param
(
     # Этот параметр принимает строку, если он не передан скрипту,
     # то по умолчанию берется имя текущего пользователя.
     # https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.getcurrent.aspx

     [string]$UserName = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Name
)

Write-Host $UserName
```

Запускать из Планировщика Задач следующим способом:

```
powershell.exe -File "myscript.ps1" -UserName "Ololosha Valueva"
```

Answer (score 2):

посмотрите в сторону переменных окружения. создайте переменную окружения `User_name`. Из Powershell'а взаимодействовать с ней можно следующим образом:

```
$env:User_name = "value"
```